# sh: 1: nuxt: not found when trying to dockerise the Nuxt app

Tags: javascript, docker, nuxt.js

`sh: 1: nuxt: not found` I'm always getting this error when trying to run the docker container.
It's only working when I have node modules and a .nuxt folder mounted from my local. As soon as I delete them, that docker container starts giving the same error.
Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.14
WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json ./
RUN npm install
ADD . .
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: myapp-nuxt
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
    depends_on:
      - "server"
    environment:
      - NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - NUXT_PORT=3001
    network_mode: "host"
    command: npm run dev
```

PS - I tried following almost all tutorials. Issue is same with all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `volumes:` block hides absolutely everything that the Dockerfile does and overwrites it with different content from your host.  More specifically, it hides the `node_modules` directory generated by `RUN npm install` and replaces it with whatever might happen to be on the host in that directory.  You don't need this `volumes:` block and you can remove it.

```sh
# volumes:      <-- remove this block:
#   - ".:/app"  <-- don't overwrite the application code in the image
```

(Also consider removing the unnecessary `container_name:` option, moving the fixed `environment:` and `command:` settings into your Dockerfile, and not disabling Docker networking with `network_mode: host`.  You can probably get the Compose definition down to just the `build:` line, the `restart:` policy, declaring `depends_on:`, and publishing `ports:`.)

Comment: It worked like charm! Thanks!
But while editing the code it was updating real-time inside the container but now because I'm not mounting volumes, its not happening!
Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I generally use Node directly on the host for day-to-day development.