# nuxt: not found inside docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, nuxt.js

I am building a docker environment for a nuxt 3 app. This is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "prepare:hook": "husky add .husky/commit-msg \"npx --no -- commitlint --edit $1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.0.3",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.0.3",
    "@commitlint/types": "^17.0.0",
    "@formkit/nuxt": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "@formkit/themes": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "@formkit/vue": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "@nuxt/kit": "npm:@nuxt/kit-edge@latest",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.3.0",
    "@swisscom/sdx": "file:./sdx",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.5",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.2.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "luxon": "^3.0.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.16",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "vue": "^3.2.37"
  }
}
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - NPM_TOKEN=${NPM_TOKEN}
        - NPM_MAIL=${NPM_MAIL}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - smap_db:/usr/db/smap
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${DB_USER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
volumes:
  smap_db:
    external: true
```

And this is my `Dockerfile` for the nuxt 3 app:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:18.6.0-bullseye

ARG NPM_TOKEN
ARG NPM_MAIL

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/bin/smap

# Install dependencies
COPY .npmrc package.json sdx ./
RUN npm install
RUN rm -f .npmrc

# Copy the app
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

This is my `.dockerignore` file:

```
# Dependencies
node_modules

# Editor
.vscode

# Build outputs
.nuxt
.output
dist

# Commitlint
.husky
commitlint.config.ts

# Other
README.md
```

When I run `docker compose up` I get the following error from building the docker file:

```
=> ERROR [7/7] RUN npm run build                                                                                                                      0.8s
------
 > [7/7] RUN npm run build:
#0 0.796
#0 0.796 > build
#0 0.796 > nuxt build
#0 0.796
#0 0.803 /tmp/build6594337338.sh: 2: nuxt: not found
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 127
```

Here is what I have tried so far to solve this:

- Deleted all containers, volumes etc. associated with my app and then rebuild everything
- Reset docker to factory settings
- Deactivated the buildkit feature
- Commented everything out in the `.dockerignore`
- Tried the following image versions from node:

  - `node:18.6.0-bullseye`
  - `node:18.6.0`
  - `node:18.6.0-alpine`
  - `node:18`

All of this didn't help and I always got the same error.

Why is the `nuxt` command not found inside the docker container? Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone know how I can fix this?

#### Update

I set the `NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL` to `info`. The error is still the same but with some additional information:

```
=> ERROR [8/8] RUN npm run build                                                                                                                      1.7s
------
 > [8/8] RUN npm run build:
#0 1.641 npm info using npm@8.15.0
#0 1.642 npm info using node@v18.7.0
#0 1.642 npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
#0 1.643 npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
#0 1.643 npm timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 5ms
#0 1.643 npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 6ms
#0 1.643 npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
#0 1.644 npm timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
#0 1.644 npm timing config:load:file:/usr/bin/smap/.npmrc Completed in 2ms
#0 1.644 npm timing config:load:project Completed in 5ms
#0 1.644 npm timing config:load:file:/root/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
#0 1.644 npm timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
#0 1.645 npm timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 6ms
#0 1.645 npm timing config:load:global Completed in 6ms
#0 1.645 npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 2ms
#0 1.645 npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
#0 1.645 npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
#0 1.645 npm timing config:load Completed in 28ms
#0 1.645 npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 28ms
#0 1.645 npm timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
#0 1.645 npm timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
#0 1.645 npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
#0 1.646 npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
#0 1.646 npm timing npm:load:display Completed in 9ms
#0 1.653 npm timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 7ms
#0 1.653 npm timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
#0 1.654 npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
#0 1.656 npm timing npm:load Completed in 50ms
#0 1.667
#0 1.667 > build
#0 1.667 > nuxt build
#0 1.667
#0 1.675 /tmp/build-27aedcc8.sh: 1: nuxt: not found
#0 1.677 npm timing command:run Completed in 15ms
#0 1.678 npm timing npm Completed in 74ms
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 127
```

Comment: Tried with Node16? It's probably not related to your issue but who knows? Also, did you checked some questions there on that same topic? Sorry, I don't have a lot of experience with Docker.

Comment: I just tried it with node 16 and got the same error :( I am reasearching this problem now for about three days and haven't found an answer. I will open an issue on the [nodejs/docker-node](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node) github if I don't get an answer here.

Comment: You can try few more things here and see if it does help. First remove copying the `.npmrc` before installing the node modules in the container. And second, add a `RUN ls node_modules/` and see if nuxt is indeed installed after the `npm install`.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem using [nuxt 3 quickstart](http://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/quick-start) and the same dockerfile/docker-compose, however it ran successfully in Docker. Please can you try the same activity, if it fails then it could be a problem with your local setup, if it works then it's more likely a problem with your app.

Comment: @MelkisH. Thanks, that helped a lot. I could solve the problem with your input. I'll ad an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sooo, this was kind of a dummy moment from me. Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/129312335?noredirect=1) I was able to solve the issue.
On my dockerfile I had this line of code `COPY .npmrc package.json sdx ./`. Sdx is an internal package of my company and in this project I use it to test some new features that still are in development in production mode, thats why the docker container. This package of course has a `package.json` and this one overwrote my `package.json`.
I simply removed the `sdx` from the `COPY` command and made a new `COPY` for `sdx` the line after. `COPY ./sdx ./sdx`.

Comment: But does the hot reload still function?

Comment: In order for hmr to work you need to expose the hmr port

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because my Docker was setup incorrectly, resulting in an empty `node_modules` folder inside the container.

Specifically, my `docker-compose.yml` had a typical volume mapping as so:

```
  frontend:
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
```

If you have not ran `yarn` or `npm install` locally, this will cause your local directory to overwrite the container's directory, replacing its `node_modules` with an empty folder, and therefore not finding `nuxt` as a command.

Fix this by using a named volume instead:

```
  frontend:
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
```

You retain the volume mapping so you get things like hot-reloading, but it will effectively "exclude" `node_modules` from being mapped. It also names the volume so it's identifiable in your Docker volumes list.

Credits:

- [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72011761/10334441) for pointing out the root issue and providing a solution.
- [@Nate T](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38601156/10334441) for the idea to use named volumes.